# Typescript boolean function must return a value

Tags: typescript

I have following Typescript boolean function:

```
checkRiskValues(): boolean {
    this.controlsName.forEach((item) => {
        this.threatForm.get(item)!.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            this.valueControlArray.push(this.threatForm.get(item)!.value);

            if (this.valueControlArray.indexOf(true) > -1)
                return true;

            else
                return false
        });
    });
}
```

The method appears error the function must return value. I know it, but I'm not sure how to implement this true/false statement outside foreach scope ?

If I call if/else statament outside foreach loop result is always false because

```
if (this.valueControlArray.indexOf(true) > -1)
```

is empty..

**EDIT**

I've deleted checkRiskValues() function and add complete logic in ngOnInit() method and I'have also added valueControl varibable that keep true/false value and pass in another function. Thanks everyone..This my solution:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.controlsName.forEach((item) => {
        this.threatForm.get(item)!.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            this.valueControlArray.push(this.threatForm.get(item)!.value);

            if (this.valueControlArray.indexOf(true) > -1) {
                this.valueControl = true;

            }
            else {
                this.valueControl = false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello your problem is that forEach works with a callback function.

Answer (score 4):

This is my proposal:

```
checkRiskValues(): boolean {
    return setRiskValues().indexOf(true) > -1;
}

setRiskValues(): Array<any> {
    let values = [];
    this.controlsName.forEach((item) => {
        this.threatForm.get(item)!.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            values.push(this.threatForm.get(item)!.value);
        });
    });

    return values;
}
```

This way you are:

1. Building your array
2. Checking if exists a positive value (if true is present will return the index)

Comment: None of the solutions work..I just need status this method on the end (true/false)

Comment: What is returning my method setRiskValues() ??

Comment: The problem here is that the code is filling the values by subscribing to `valueChanges` which is an observable. Because value changes happen on user actions, `push` won't be called while this function is running, so the return value will always be an empty array